# Working with Node::Buffers in C++ Node Addons

Tags: c++, node.js, v8, node.js-addon

I'm working on a Node addon that encrypts data using Windows DPAPI. I'm passing two Javascript Uint8Array to the C++ code using NAN.

This is what the typescript interface looks like:

```
export interface DpapiBindings{
    protectData(dataToEncrypt: Uint8Array, optionalEntropy: Uint8Array, scope: string): Uint8Array
}
```

I'd like to then create a Node::Buffer in the C++ code:

```cpp
void ProtectData( Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE info)
{
    v8::Isolate* isolate = info.GetIsolate();

   // 
    auto buffer = node::Buffer::Data(info[0]);
    auto len = node::Buffer::Length(info[0]);

    DATA_BLOB entropyBlob;
    entropyBlob.pbData = nullptr;
    if (!info[1]->IsNull())
    {
        entropyBlob.pbData = reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(node::Buffer::Data(info[1]));
        entropyBlob.cbData = node::Buffer::Length(info[1]);
    }

    DATA_BLOB dataIn;
    DATA_BLOB dataOut;

    // initialize input data
    dataIn.pbData = reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(buffer);
    dataIn.cbData = len;

    success = CryptProtectData(
            &dataIn,
            nullptr,
            entropyBlob.pbData ? &entropyBlob : nullptr,
            nullptr, 
            nullptr,
            flags,
            &dataOut);

    auto returnBuffer = Nan::CopyBuffer(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(dataOut.pbData), dataOut.cbData).ToLocalChecked();
    LocalFree(dataOut.pbData);

    info.GetReturnValue().Set(returnBuffer);

}
```

I'm new to C++, my question is: When working with node::Buffer::Data and node::Buffer::Length in C++ code, and calling into CryptProtectData, do I need to worry about buffer overflows? If so, how do I protect against it? Should I be appending a null char to buffer and len?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62676223/980129).

Comment: @Manuel, thanks that's helpful. I've edited my question with a follow up.

Comment: @gonzalez you set the length in `dataIn.cbData = len` so no, no overflow. As for the `null` `char`, if it is there at input it will be part of the encrypted buffer. You can check for it in `buffer[len - 1]`. If it isn't there you'll need to add it after unencryption (if it is a string.)

Comment: @Manuel To make sure I understand correctly: overflow for dataIn.pbData is not a problem because we set the length in dataIn.cbData, so we know how many bytes there are. Is this the same case for dataIn.cbData? Do I need to ensure that  dataIn.cbData (in my case node::Buffer::Length(info[1])) is null terminated since we are not passing in the length?

Comment: dataIn.cbData has the size of the buffer received, whether this has the `null` or not I can't say as it is a `Uint8Array` from JS and it is a byte array. I guess you don't need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to worry about overflow. The `dataIn` and `dataOut` structures are pointers with a length.

BufferCopy is not what you want to use though. You want to use: `Nan::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> Nan::NewBuffer(char* data, uint32_t size)`.

https://github.com/nodejs/nan/blob/master/doc/buffers.md#api_nan_new_buffer

and make sure you free the `dataOut.pbData` memory when you're done (i see you are with the `LocalFree` call.) the reason it can't overflow is that `CryptProtectData` allocates that buffer based on the size it needs.